# How to call a button from a table?

Tags: javascript, button, html

I am making a shortkey for a webpage that clicks a button when a press my ESC key instead of having to mouse down and click it. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('idOrderOpenTable').openMarketOrdersTable[1].click();
```

[image: button]

Comment: is  "idOrderOpenTable" tag name?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a children from `<table id="idOrderOpenTable"></table>` with `document.getElementsByTagName` method but you should use `document.querySelector`.
For example:

```
document.querySelector("#idOrderOpenTable .openCancelBtn").click()
```

Comment: Thanks that works! simple answer. First time JS user and i just need a quick solution. Thanks again

Comment: Its ok when you are new in language

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this example and modify it per your needs,

```js
function keydownFunction(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 27){
    document.getElementById("button").click();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onkeydown="keydownFunction(event)">

<div >Test <input type="button" value="Button" id="button" onclick="alert('Hello');"/></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The script looks for the `esc` key pressed and invokes the click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

To find your button in a table, use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It returns the first element that matches your query.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('openMarketOrdersTable').querySelector('.openCloseBtn');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  var isESC = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) === 27;
  
  if(isESC) {
  
    button.click();
    
  }
  
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  console.log('Button was clicked.');

});
```

```html
<table id="openMarketOrdersTable">
  <tbody>
    <th>
      <button class="openCloseBtn">Press me with an ESC.</button>
    </th>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: timofey's solution is simple and works for my purposes. I am using it in conjunction with shortkeys for Chrome Browser so it runs his line perfectly with out me knowing much about JS or typing extra code. But thanks!